# active directory login control

Tags: active-directory

Can we find automatically who is online or offline in active directory.Has active directory got status field  For example ,if someone  connects the network , status  field is set online in active directory . Is it possible
Thank you.

Comment: The simple answer to your question is 'no'. Nothing informs the AD about logins.

Answer (score 2):

unfortinatly there is no direct way to do that on active directory which you want but you can do this different ways by using third party applications or checking windows event logs.

Get user logon info by command line by using PsLoggedon https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psloggedon

Usage of psloggedon:

**psloggedon [- ] [-l] [-x] [\computername | username]**

**[- ]**:Displays the supported options and the units of measurement used for output values.

**[-l]**:Shows only local logons instead of both local and network resource logons.

**[-x]**:Don't show logon times.

**[\\computername]**:Specifies the name of the computer for which to list logon information.

**[username]**:If you specify a user name PsLoggedOn searches the network for computers to which that user is logged on. This is useful if you want to ensure that a particular user is not logged on when you are about to change their user profile configuration.

[PsLoggedOn ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzAVa.png)

diffirent way using auditing applications like ManageEngine adaudit,Netwrix Auditor, Lepide Auditor etc. will be answer your questions.

ps:for ManageEngine adaudit **Server Audit -> Local Logon-Logoff ->Logon Activity** tab like screenshot below

[AdAudit ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udCdP.png)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such field in the Active Directory. You could only check the logins in the Event Monitor.